# How to take content item package with all referenced items using Sitecore Powershell?

Tags: powershell-extensions, packages

I would like to create `package` of one single content item using `Sitecore PowerShell Extensions`. While creating the package, I would like to include all the referenced items in the package. Is there any script available to solve this task?

I know only the content item path, in that I need to include referenced template, media,etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like to add the referenced items into your package using `PowerShell` then you need to use `Get-ItemReference` to get all the referenced items of the item that you want to include in your package. And then you need to loop through all the items to put them into your package and then the package will be created with the referenced items that you need. So the code should be something like this.

```
# Pass your item ID 
$items = Get-ItemReference -ID "{56305117-8C9C-4C08-96D5-BB97A8E27419}"

$package = New-Package "Sitecore Package";

# Set package metadata
$package.Sources.Clear();

$package.Metadata.Author = "Sumit";
$package.Metadata.Publisher = "Sumit";
$package.Metadata.Version = "1.0";
$package.Metadata.Readme = 'Readme Text'

# Loop on all the related items and add into the package
ForEach ($item in $items) {

    $source = $item | New-ExplicitItemSource -Name 'Your Page Name' -InstallMode Overwrite
    $package.Sources.Add($source);
}

# Save package
Export-Package -Project $package -Path "$($package.Name)-$($package.Metadata.Version).zip" -Zip

# Offer the user to download the package
Download-File "$SitecorePackageFolder\$($package.Name)-$($package.Metadata.Version).zip"
```

Hope this will help.

Some useful links.

How to create a package.

https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/packaging/new-package

Get item references.

https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/get-itemreference

Get Item Renderings

https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items/item-renderings

Comment: Is it take Datasource reference content items and it's template items?

Comment: It will give you all the items that return by the `Get-ItemReference` function. Like template, rendering, media items etc. Also if you want to get any particular item then you can extend this logic to get items and keep them into a variable and then loop through this and add it to your Sitecore Package.

Comment: @Astle If you want to get only the renderings set on an item then you need to follow this article https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items/item-renderings and then write logic to create loop and then add it to your Sitecore package.

Comment: Careful with `-InstallMode Overwrite` that may cause lost of data. If one reference has children not in the package, they will be removed. I suggest to just remove it and let the installer decide later, or use `-InstallMode Merge  -MergeMode Merge` for safety